# Setting View's atribute that is in child fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

[image: My layout]

I want to access Views that are in Fragment's children that are put in ViewPager. The idea is to toggle (disable/enable) spinners when button is pressed. Spinners are placed in separate fragments that are displayed in ViewPager controlled by TabLayout:

```js
// Snippet of code from Fragment A

final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

Fragment childFragment = new Fragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.viewPager, childFragment).commit();

ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(childFragment.getFragmentManager());

adapter.AddFragment(new fragment_unositelj(), "FragmentB");
adapter.AddFragment(new fragment_voditelj(), "FragmentC");
adapter.AddFragment(new fragment_pratitelj(), "FragmentD");

viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
FragmentB = viewPager.findViewById(R.id.FragmentB);
FragmentC = viewPager.findViewById(R.id.FragmentC);
FragmentD = viewPager.findViewById(R.id.FragmentD);
```

I don't know how to achieve to set Spinner disabled / enabled in all fragment children's spinner. I tried to set public variable in MainActivity and to control Spinners attribute based on that, but I am not sure in which lifecycle part to place it because fragment B is inflated initialy, and others are when TabItem clicked. I hope I could describe my problem properly. If anything more is needed please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: It's easy if you use EventBus or ViewModel, and won't face lifecycle problem

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround for this problem, I am not sure if it is correct way, but for now it works for me. In FragmentB,FragmentC,FragmentD i added

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View getView() {
    if (((MainActivity) getActivity()).getStatus() == 1) {
        mySpinner.setEnabled( true );
    } else
        mySpinner.setEnabled( false );
    return super.getView();

}
```

//(MainActivity) getActivity()).getStatus() - method that returns state if it shold be enabled